# PHP: Saving weekday + the two times

Tags: php

I am trying to make so you can select your availability time, monday to sunday, from xx:00 to xx:00.

For the HTML i did a for loop, outputting the weekdays checkbox and two time options, looks like this:

[jsfiddle.net/Sbcbg](http://%20jsfiddle.net/Sbcbg)

the source:

```
$weekDays = array('Måndag', 'Tisdag', 'Onsdag', 'Torsdag', 'Fredag', 'Lördag', 'Söndag');
echo '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300">';
    for($i=0; $i<count($weekDays); $i++){
     echo '<tr><td>';
     echo '<input type="checkbox" name="day'.$i.'">'.$weekDays[$i].'</option>';
     echo '</td><td>';
     echo '<select>';       
        for($f=23; $f>18; $f--){
         echo ' <option name="from'.$i.'" select="">'.$f.':00</option> ';
        }
     echo '</select>';
     echo ' till ';
     echo '<select>';
        for($t=0; $t<10; $t++){
         echo ' <option name="from'.$i.'" select="">'.$t.':00</option> ';
        }
     echo '</select>';
     echo '</td></tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
```

How should I know what are what for the saving part?

How can I see if one weekday is checked, and if it is then take the two option values (the two times) and output them?

So if you check Tisdag(Tuesday) and select time 22:00 and in the other you select time 04:00, then it should output that you have checked Tuesday 22:00-04:00 when you submit the form.

Thanks in forward

Comment: To get more insight in what is sent to the server when the user submits the form you can dump the contents of $_POST.

Comment: Meaning, do a `var_dump($_POST)`; on top just to see what's what

Comment: Notice that the second inner for loop (till) should output <option name="till'.$i.'" select=""> and not <option name="from'.$i.'" select="">

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some mismatched tags here.  For example:

```
'<input type="checkbox" name="day'.$i.'">'.$weekDays[$i].'</option>'
```

You are closing an option that you never open.

I think you want a checkbox to indicate that this day is day that has some availability.  I would recommend changing it to:

```
'<label for="day'.$i.'"><input type="checkbox" name="day'.$i.'" value="1"/>'.$weekDays[$i].'</label>'
```

Then for your selects, you want to define the name of the selects and the values of the options.  The name will then be the index in the `$_POST` array, and the value will be the value of the `option` the user selected.

Such as:

```
echo '<select name="from'.$i.'">';       
    for($f=23; $f>18; $f--){
     echo ' <option value="'.$f.':00">'.$f.':00</option> ';
    }
 echo '</select>';
```

Then your submit checks would look something like:

```
for($i = 0; $i< 7; $i++) {
    if(isset($_POST['day'.$i]) && ($_POST['day'.$i] == 1) {
        $from = $_POST['from'.$i];
        $to = $_POST['to'.$i];
        //do something with this data
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks about right to me too, but you really need to clean up that html or you will get all kinds of nasty and varied results from different browsers trying to correct it in different ways.

Comment: @meterainer, how do you mean?  It looks like valid XHTML to me.  The interleaving of the PHP and the HTML is a little ugly, but I was just copying Karem's style and looks valid.